# How to save JSON parsing values to an array in ArduinoJson

Tags: arrays, json, parsing, arduino, arduinojson

Arduino users, help pls! Hi guys! For example, I have a JSON document for parsing ArduinoJson:

```
{
  "id": [
    1,
    7,
    32,
    9656
  ]
}
```

I need to save the id values so that they look like:

**ids[0] = 1,**

**ids[1] = 7,**

**ids[2] = 32and so on.**

Now I'm doing like this (I know that it's fundamentally wrong, but I don't know how else):

*I'll skip the step of request by the link*

```
char json[500];
  getids.toCharArray(json, 500);
  Serial.println(json);
  StaticJsonDocument <500> doc;
  DeserializationError err = deserializeJson(doc, json);
```

Then I just try to equal values to the array :

```
int ids[16] = {doc["id"]};
```

But when I output ids[0], I get **0**

Also, the problem is that I do not know in advance how many elements will be in this array - this file is regularly edited in the phone app and my JSON document can change the number of ids. Now there are 4 of them, but this is as an example, because their number is unknown, which makes it necessary to make a dynamic array, and not set it yourself, as I set [16]

ArduinoJson assistant offers this option:

```
JsonArray id = doc["id"];
int id_0 = id[0]; // 1
int id_1 = id[1]; // 7
int id_2 = id[2]; // 1337
int id_3 = id[3]; // 9656
```

But this does not fit, because, again, I do not know the number of elements in advance

This is my first question on Stackoverflow, so I'm sorry if I asked it incorrectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's may just use like:

```
JsonArray ids = doc["id"]
```

and use it inside functions like ids[1], ids[2] and other